# The title of the page during the maintenance is not translated

Tags: feature-request, localization, transifex, international-sites, maintenance

During the maintenance the title of the site is "We are Offline". It's not translated, and there is no such string in traducir/transifex.

Could you add this string into Transifex?

Comment: Other texts on that page are translated / in traducir?

Comment: @rene yes, the text on the page itself was translated.

Comment: Okay, I was just checking if that page would be up for translation at all. Carry on then ;)